# >" after image in wordpress php code

Tags: php, wordpress

I am dynamically adding images to a post in wp using php. I am able to pull the post thumbnail image from the post by using `the_post_thumbnail();` function, however there is showing `">` after the image. I have tried to play around  with the following line, but cannot get rid of the `">`.

```
<img src="<?php echo the_post_thumbnail();?>">
```

I have tried each way i could think of but cannot figure it out.

Please see complete code below the image.

[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nw2qf.png)

```
<?php $query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=5' ); ?>

<?php while ($query -> have_posts()) : $query -> the_post(); ?>

<div class="blog">
    <img src="<?php echo the_post_thumbnail();?>">
</div>
```

Comment: Dont use <img src="">

Comment: @Jonas : Why don't ? How to this do in an other way ?

Comment: Basic debugging: look at your browser's "view source". If you'd done that, you'd see that `the_post_thumbnail()` ALREADY outputs a full `<img>` tag, so you're producing `<img src="<img src="....">">`

Comment: @Jonas, ok, understood.

Comment: @MarcB was a bit of an easy one to solve, should have cracked it myself, but fairly new to php! cheers!

Comment: when buidilng html, never go off what the browser shows you. It's job is to LIE to you by "rendering" what it's given. that means you're not seeing your actual output, you're seeing what the browser THINKS you want to see. always go directly to 'view source' when you have unexpected html glitches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the img tag and just echo `the_post_thumbnail()`, this function already deals with the img tags. See [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails)

```
<div class="blog">
    <?php echo the_post_thumbnail();?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use your img tag because are you embedding some classes or some you must fund the thumbnail url with:

```
the_post_thumbnail_url();
```

and you can specify the size inside the ()
ej:

```
the_post_thumbnail_url('full');
```